# SAS - proc cusum not found

Tags: sas, statistics, statistical-sampling

I have the following SAS code:

```
data vis;
input v;
datalines;
3169
3173
3162
3154
3139
3145
3160
3172
3175
3205
3203
3209
3208
3211
3214
3215
3209
3203
3185
3187
3192
3199
3197
3193
3190
3183
3197
3188
3183
3175
3174
3171
3180
3179
3175
3174
;

proc cusum data=vis;
xchart v / scheme = twosided
mu0 = 3200
sigma0 = 0.050
delta = 1
h = 8.01
k = 0.25;
run;
```

When I run the code, I get the error that proc cusum is not found. Why is that the case? I've triple checked with the SAS documentation and found nothing wrong with my code. Some insight into this will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have SAS/QC.

Run PROC SETINIT or PROC PRODUCT_STATUS to make sure it is licensed and installed.

Comment: I'm using the SAS University edition and running it on SAS studio. However I tried running the commands above in my code but it does not seem to produce any results.

Comment: Output will be in the LOG and not in the OUTPUT window.

Comment: SAS University Edition does not include SAS/QC.

Comment: @Tom Then is there any way to generate the CUSUM Tableau in the SAS University Edition?